# 'Invoke-Webrequest' works fine on prompt but fails when executed through Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am using a PowerShell script to get a dynamic file name from a web page.

When I run below code on a PowerShell prompt it returns output of the filename, e.g. `abcxyz.jpeg`.

```
((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ‘http://myurl.x.y/abc/pqr/’).Links | Where innerHTML -like “abc*.jpeg”).href
```

Then I copied the code to a Jenkins job executing PowerShell script.

Here instead of returning the filename, I see below error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer’s first-launch configuration is not complete....

I have tried replacing `Invoke-WebRequest` with `wget`, using `-useBasicParsing`, etc. Some sites recommended to open and configure Internet Explorer, which was already done,  Nevertheless I tried those too.

Jenkins Job runs with user Administrator. All other PowerShell commands such as reading a file, updating a file works fine, but I get error only in above command.

So if `Invoke-WebRequest` works fine from a PowerShell command prompt then why doesn't it work through a Jenkins Job? The PowerShell script was executed on the same slave machine where I'm executing the job.

I assume this is more to do with Jenkins environment, please advice.

Comment: I suspect that the IE first launch configuration has been done for your user, but not the Jenkins user. Did you enter "Internet Explorer’s first-launch configuration is not complete" in your preferred search engine? It should give you a metric ton of results. Did you follow the advice given in those results?

Comment: Have you tried `to open and configure Internet Explorer` under `Administrator` user?

Comment: Many Thanks @AnsgarWiechers and beatcracker for directing me towards configure internet explorer... I was assuming the issue was on Jenkins end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for "Internet Explorer’s first-launch configuration is not complete"
I came across [a link](http://wahlnetwork.com/2015/11/17/solving-the-first-launch-configuration-error-with-powershells-invoke-webrequest-cmdlet/)! . Needed to follow the steps to resolve it. However I windows 2012 server, I was not able to find Group Policy Object dialog window.

Then came across [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736591(v=ws.10).aspx)! to find Group Policy Object window.

The steps are in command line window ( run gpedit.msc and click ok )

Scroll through the highlighted sections in attached image [image]and open "prevent running first run wizard". Once you are able to open it up. Follow the steps in first link.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue few days back and I resolved it by applying the proxy settings in the "Invoke-WebRequest" call.

Something like this;

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url -Proxy 'http://10.10.7.11:80' -ProxyCredential $creds
```